# How to say "to google something" in French?

Tags: traduction, informatique, néologismes

As a german speaker with a French background, I was wondering how "to google" would translate in French. "Googler qqch" seems wrong.

Comment: It seems wrong and yet it is tolerated. It is defined on the [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/googler). You can also choose "_rechercher (sur Google)_", but it is quite longer.

Comment: That would mostly depend on the context. To a friend, you could use the mark as a verb. In a formal context, you definitely wouldn't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*Google*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google) is a [trademark](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=google&submit.x=0&submit.y=0) for a [popular](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_%28moteur_de_recherche%29) *search engine* (*moteur de recherche* : [Franceterme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=search%20engine&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), [Termium](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2075047), [GDT](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&codom2nd=&srchtxt=SEARCH%20ENGINE)). Only *Termium* lists the verb based thereupon and provides a translation, "[*googler*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=GOOGLER)"; incidentally it also lists the [*googler*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=GOOGLER) (noun), *the person who uses the search engine to find information on the Internet*, and provides "*googler/googleur*(Fr.)" in that case.<sup>1</sup> The verb has certainly been used in French.

---

[*Collins*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/google) suggests "**chercher + sur/avec**" as suggested in another [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16027). It also covers this typical scenario where the search term is explicitly stated within the sentence using the verb "[**taper**](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/taper/76647?q=taper#75757)" : "*J'ai tapé `vols bon marché pour Mumbai' dans Google.*" (*Collins*). These verbs are very usual in context.

---

<sub>1. It's interesting to look back on some articles from 10-15 years ago on the topic; an [article](http://www.lemonde.fr/archives/article/2003/08/22/je-google-tu-googles-nous-googlons_331334_1819218.html?xtmc=googler&xtcr=17) (2003) references concerns for the "*dégénérescence de la marque*" when used casually as a noun etc.. Another [article](http://www.itrnews.com/articles/55580/googleur-sachant-googler-son-google.html) (2006) claims *Google* recommended against using their name as a verb and preferred « *effectuer une recherche sur Internet avec Google* ». Please note the answer takes no stance on whether the verb *to google* means *to google with Google* or *to search with any search engine* in English; the *AmHDoEL* entry didn't specify and it is off topic. The point is just *Termium* has identified some sort of meaningful use in French and connected it to the English form. *Franceterme*, *GDT* and *Larousse* don't have the verb: they have the "*moteur de recherche*". "*Googler*" yields no *ngrams* from the French corpus.</sub>

Comment: Parfois on dit "*J'ai cherché sur Gogole ...*", en pensant à Nicolas Gogol dont le mysticisme et la fin de vie donne l'image d'un homme 'original et dérangé' :) .

Comment: ‘Google’ as an English verb (at least in my neck of the Am-English-speaking world) has already “succumbed” to the double-edged sword of trademark genericization/dilution (one can google with Bing, just as one can xerox with a Canon here in Va.), whereas this seems not to be (or less of) the case in Francophonia.  I find it interesting, telling even, that in the English entry on the Termium page you cite there are ellipses [of the unnecessary, wink-wink, the following is added solely to appease our (and Google’s) lawyers variety] following “Web,” whereas none are found in the French entry.

Answer (score 6):

You may use "*Google-le*" when talking about a specific subject. Otherwise there is an expression: "*Google est ton ami*" : "Google is your friend" to obviously suggest someone to do his own research...

Comment: Good point. I actually heard "Google est ton ami".

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid no one-word answer to this question could be accepted as a valid French verb. Any applicable one would be nothing but convenient jargon. I have heard *googliser* as well as *googler*. A proper way of saying that would simply be *(re)chercher sur Google*.

In English though, I thought "to googlize" was more commonly used as "to google" for this meaning, but it might simply not be the case anymore. It's just a matter of fashion in my opinion...

Comment: I have **heard** the same ones *googler* [gugle] and *googliser* [gugœlize] with a preference for the first one among practitioners of the fact...

Comment: In English I've never heard "to googlize" until now.

Answer (score 2):

One would say "chercher sur Google" or "faire une recherche sur Google" but one can expect that "gougler" would probably be understood even though it would sound a bit strange as it has not been officially frenchified yet.